# update/insert/delete sql records based on c# list with modified data

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Suppose I have 5 elements in list referenced by two foriegn keys in sql

```
pk  name    country fk
1   james   usa     12
2   smith   canada  12
3   micheal usa     12
4   micheal usa     13
5   micheal usa     13
```

on get request of my api i send 12 as a foreign key id and get the list as following

```
1   james   usa     12
2   smith   canada  12
3   micheal usa     12
```

when I removed elements 2 and 3 and updated the list with new element primary key 0

```
1   james   usa     12
0   sam     africa  12
```

my new data in sql should look like that.

```
1   james   usa     12
4   micheal usa     13 
5   micheal usa     13
6   sam     africa  12
```

I have tried using merge statement in sql for insert update delete in same query, but the problem with merge is that its removing the other elements too with id 13.

My stored procedure using merge.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_insert_update_patientlifehistory]
@patientlifehistory as UT_PatientLifeHistory readonly 
as
begin
  merge tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY 
  using @patientlifehistory as s
  on (
    tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY.PAT_ID = s.PAT_ID or 
    tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY.PATLI_ID = s.PATLI_ID
  )

  when matched then 

  UPDATE set 
  PAT_SUBJECT = s.PAT_SUBJECT
  ,PAT_HISTORY = s.PAT_HISTORY

  when not matched by target then

  INSERT
  (PAT_SUBJECT, PAT_HISTORY, PAT_ID) VALUES
  (s.pat_subject, s.pat_history, s.PAT_ID)

  when not matched by source then
  DELETE;
END
```

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY (
  [PATLI_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  [PAT_SUBJECT] [varchar](20) NULL,
  [PAT_HISTORY] [varchar](30) NULL,
  [PAT_ID] [int] NULL 
  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tPatient(PAT_ID), 
  [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((1)), ) 

CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UT_PatientLifeHistory] AS TABLE( 
  [PATLI_ID] [int] NULL, 
  [PAT_SUBJECT] [varchar](200) NOT NULL, 
  [PAT_HISTORY] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
  [PAT_ID] [int] NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Can you please post the table `DDL` for `tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY` and `UT_PatientLifeHistory`?  And I assume you are using `SQLServer`, is that correct?

Comment: yes i am using sql the DDL for tpatient_lifehistory is    

`CREATE TABLE tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY
(
 [PATLI_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [PAT_SUBJECT] [varchar](20) NULL,
 [PAT_HISTORY] [varchar](30) NULL,
 [PAT_ID] [int] NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tPatient(PAT_ID),
 [IS_ACTIVE] [bit] NULL DEFAULT ((1)),
)`

UT_PatientLifeHistor is Table Valued Parameter

`CREATE TYPE [dbo].[UT_PatientLifeHistory] AS TABLE(
 [PATLI_ID] [int] NULL,
 [PAT_SUBJECT] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
 [PAT_HISTORY] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
 [PAT_ID] [int] NOT NULL
)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to `MERGE` the data from the "src" table to the "tgt" table below:

```
-- src
pk  name    country fk
1   james   usa     12
4   micheal usa     13
5   micheal usa     13
6   sam     africa  12

-- tgt
pk  name    country fk
1   james   usa     12
2   smith   canada  12
3   micheal usa     12
4   micheal usa     13
5   micheal usa     13
```

Usually when you do a `MERGE` you specify only the `PK` columns in your `ON` clause, so that you do not have multiple source rows trying to update a single target row.

Is `PATLI_ID` the `PK` of the `tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY` table?  Can you change your `ON` clause to only reference that field instead of using an `OR` clause.  Something like:

```sql
  merge tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY 
  using @patientlifehistory as s
  on tPATIENT_LIFEHISTORY.PATLI_ID = s.PATLI_ID
```

**Update**
In real terms, for a given patient, I think you're trying to update his existing life history data with a current set of life history data.  If that is the case, and assuming the `PATLI_ID` value is retained in your "src" data, then it might make sense to change your `OR` to an `AND` in your `ON` clause.  That way you're matching to see if there are existing life history items for a given patient.

[SQL Server MERGE](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-merge/)

Comment: `PATL_ID` is primary key and `PAT_ID` is foreign key i need to do crud based on foreign key and primary key. i have tired `AND` and `ON` also

Comment: If your `(fk=13)` rows are getting deleted, then it sounds like they are not falling under the `WHEN MATCHED` or `WHEN NOT MATCHED` conditions.  Looking at one row `(pk=4)` with respect to your `ON` condition, this row matches two rows in the "target" table `(pk=4 and pk=5)`.  I'm not 100% sure, but maybe this is related to what you're seeing.  Sorry, I don't think I can help beyond that.

Comment: its foreign key not primary key `fk=13` i need to update only `fk=13` values not others with respect to their primary key `pk`